# Problema para programar boton que ejecute una acción al presionar y otra diferente mientras permanezca presionado

Tags: android

Tengo un botón con el icono + para modificar la cantidad. Lo que quiero es que el usuario pueda clickear de uno en uno la cantidad o que mantenga oprimido el botón y la cantidad aumente hasta que el usuario suelte el botón, ¿Como hago esto en android studio?

Tengo programado el botón en onClick y me aumenta la cantidad sin problema. Para la segunda opción he probado con onLongClick, pero solo he conseguido que aplique la función una vez, no que se repita mientras se mantenga apretado. ¿Es problema de usar el onLongClick o de que la función asociada no está bien programada?

El código que tengo escrito hasta ahora es este:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int val = 40;
Button BtnAdd,BtnRemove;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    showValue(val);
    BtnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
    BtnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addValue();
        }
    });

    BtnAdd.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                  public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                                          addValue2();//se que esto no es correcto, pero no he sido capaz de encontrar la función correcta

                                          return false;
                                      }
                                  }
    );

public void addValue(){
    if (val==100){
        val = val;
    }
    else{
        val = val+1;
    }
    showValue(val);
}

public void addValue2(){
    if (val==100){
        val = val;
    }
    else{
        val = val+1;
        try {
            wait(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    showValue(val);
    }

public void showValue(int val){
    TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    v.setText("" + val);
}
```

}

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta, agrega el código de lo que has resuelto y de lo que te da problemas, para así identificar que es lo que necesitas. Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido Brezniak!, te recomiendo agregues tu código, revisa como funciona el sitio., lo que sugiere con respecto a preguntas [ask]. ¿No has realizado el [tour]?.

Comment: Con un timer, pero sería bueno que pusieras algo de código.

Comment: Teneis razón, se me pasó añadir el código. Ya está solucionado.